# NSString iOS Russian encoding

Tags: ios, utf-8, nsstring, nsstringencoding, cyrillic

I'm using code below:

```
AVMetadataItem *item = [self.player.metaData objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog("%@", item.stringValue);
```

Its works good with any english song title. 
But, when i'm getting russian song title from AVMetadataItem:

```
ÐÐÐÐÐ ÐÐ¯ - ÐÐ Ð¡ÐÐ ÐÐÐÐ¢ÐÐÐ£ // Ð¡ÐÐ£Ð¨ÐÐ®Ð¢: 1585
```

How can i get something like:

```
Тратата - мы везем с собой кота.
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This might simply be an Xcode issue with the log. What happens if you display the value in a `UILabel` or some other UI element?

Comment: Same result in UILabel. Tried item.dataValue but no luck.

Comment: maybe the text is stored in UTF-8 (or some other) encoding? NSString stores everything in UTF-16.

Comment: tried:
        `for (int i = 1; i< 35; i++) { NSLog(@"%i %@", i, [[NSString alloc] initWithData:item.dataValue encoding:i]); }`
but always getting (null) or bplist00o3

Comment: try `NSUTF16*` and `NSUTF32*` constants (they have big integer values)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
NSData *test = [item.stringValue dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:test encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

We get meta from audio in UTF8 and don't know in what NSStringEncoding it's converted so i use:

```
for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
   NSData *test = [item.stringValue dataUsingEncoding:i allowLossyConversion:YES];
   NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:test encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Looks like iOS encoding Cyrillic(UTF8) in ISOLatin.